# Registering concrete type with parameter is null using Autofac

Tags: autofac

I have the following class:

```
public class Errors
{ 
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public Errors(string connectionString)
    {
         _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to register using Autofac like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<Errors>().WithParameter("connectionString", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString);
```

This object is getting injected into another object but it's always null.  Looking further into the exception, the following error message is displayed:

```
Cannot choose between multiple constructors with equal length 1 on type   'System.String'.
Select the constructor explicitly, with the UsingConstructor() configuration method, when the component is registered.
```

I've tried registering using the UsingConstructor and WithParameter and there's no change.

Answer (score 4):

Try This, there are 2 ways to register

**First Type**:

```
builder.Register(c => new Errors(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

**Second Type**:

```
public class Errors
{ 
    private string _connectionString{ get; set; }

    public Errors(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }
}
```

Register Like below

```
builder.RegisterType<Errors>().WithParameter("connectionString", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString);
```

**EDIT**: Testing

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Register(c => new Errors(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();      // Type 1
        // builder.RegisterType<Errors>().WithParameter("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString); // Type 2
        var container = builder.Build();

        var objErrors = container.Resolve<Errors>();
    }
}
```

And the config file looks like

```
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="myConn" connectionString="Some Connection String"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Please read this Autofac [Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ResolveParameters)

Tested in Autofac Version: 2.6.1.841

**Result**:
[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried the first option earlier to no avail. I just tried the second one as well and still get the same error.  I'm using Autofac version 2.6.3.862 with the MVC and WCF integrations.  All other registrations are working fine however this is the only concrete type I'm registering.  I'm also using AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource() to wire any concrete types not already registered, so wondering if their may be a conflict.

Comment: No doubt, both the types are working fine. See the EDIT post. I have tested. Make sure that your <connectionStrings> tag is proper.